# UILabel's word wrapping not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

I have a UILabel that not wrapping correctly my string as in the screenshot:

[image]

As you can see I have "composizion\ne musicale" instead of "composizio\nne musicale". In my UILabel I set number of lines = 0 and line breaks = Word Wrap. Is there other setting to set?

Comment: Try setting `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't works :(

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect it to word wrap when it's impossible for it to fit an entire word on the line? It will fall back to Char Wrapping if it cannot word wrap. Increase the width of the frame that the text is inside, and it'll word wrap instead.

If you don't know the length of the string, please use

```
 CGSize stringSize = [aString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:fontOfTheString}];
```

Then query the "width" property of the stringSize.

Comment: Hi Joey, I can't know how much will be longer the string and I'd like to have a correct word wrap

Comment: Answer edited. Change the frame to the size of the text, which you can predict.